# L'Hospital's rule and Rolle's theorem

Tags: analysis

Suppose $a$ and $b$ from $\mathbb{R}$ as $a<b$ and $f$ and $g$ two continuous function on $[a;b]$ and derivable on $]a;b[$ as $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $]a;b[$ $g{'}(x) \neq 0$.

How can I prove that $\exists$ $c$ $\in$ $]a;b[\;\;$ s.t. $\;\;\dfrac { f(b)-f(a) }{ g(b)-g(a) } =\dfrac { f^{ ' }\left( c \right)  }{ g^{ ' }\left( c \right)  } $ using Rolle's theorem.

Comment: By the way, this has a standard name, the [Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Define the function
$$
h(x)=f(x)(g(b)-g(a))-g(x)(f(b)-f(a))
$$
then $h(b)=h(a)$. Apply Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the function $$h(x) = (f(b) - f(a))g(x) - (g(b) - g(a)) f(x)$$

Comment: I like this answer, too :-)